# Can you read/write directly to hard disk from a spark job?

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs

Do the output of a spark job need to be written to hdfs and downloaded from there. Or could it be written to local file system directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fundamentally, no, you cannot use spark's native writing APIs (e.g. `df.write.parquet`) to write to local filesystem files. When running in spark local mode (on your own computer, not a cluster), you will be reading/writing from your local filesystem. However, in a cluster setting (standalone/YARN/etc), writing to HDFS is the only logical approach since partitions are [generally] contained on separate nodes.

Writing to HDFS is inherently distributed, whereas writing to local filesystem would involve at least 1 of 2 problems:

1) writing to node-local filesystem would mean files on all different nodes (5 files on 1 node, 7 files on another, etc)

2) writing to driver's filesystem would require sending all the executors' results to the driver akin to running `collect`

You can write to the driver local filesystem using traditional I/O operations built-into languages like Python or Scala.

Relevant SOs:

[How to write to CSV in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23527941/how-to-write-to-csv-in-spark)

[Save a spark RDD to the local file system using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31239161/save-a-spark-rdd-to-the-local-file-system-using-java)

[Spark (Scala) Writing (and reading) to local file system from driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38122039/spark-scala-writing-and-reading-to-local-file-system-from-driver)